# How to delete related table data

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

Sorry.
I rewrite the question, because previous question difficult to understand.

My service has a `user` table.
This table has a relationship with several tables.

I want to delete data from multiple tables associated with it.

If I want to delete all data except `A` from tables related to `user` (id:1).

[image]

In the above image, I want to delete user's data in tables B and C,
and keep A and all data related to it(ex.D).

Currently I entering the commands one by one.

```sql
delete from B where userId=1;
(await this.repository<B>.delete({userId:1});)
delete from C where userId=1;
(await this.repository<C>.delete({userId:1});)
```

But I wonder if there is a way to delete it all at once.
Because in my service more tables can be added and deleted.
If the delete command is not added or deleted, problems may occur.

The answer to the previous question was difficult to solve.

I look forward to hearing from you. thank you!

Comment: Provide complete SHOW CREATE TABLE output for each table in the scheme.

Comment: @Akina  There is no special structure. a,b,c have userId. d has the aId.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to delete all related record to user table, the only way is to set a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT with ON DELETE CASCADE, but you must remember one thing once you do this it will affect some of your data.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id_u INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(10)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e');

CREATE TABLE a (
    id_a INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name_a VARCHAR(10),
    id_u INT,
    CONSTRAINT F_ID_UA_ODC FOREIGN KEY(id_u) REFERENCES user(id_u) ON DELETE CASCADE 
)ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO a(id_u, name_a) VALUES(1,'1a'),(2,'2b'),(3,'3c'),(1,'4a'),(4,'5d');

CREATE TABLE b (
    id_b INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name_b VARCHAR(10),
    id_u INT,
    CONSTRAINT F_ID_UB_ODC FOREIGN KEY(id_u) REFERENCES user(id_u) ON DELETE CASCADE 
)ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO b(id_u,name_b) VALUES(1,'1b'),(2,'2b'),(3,'3c'),(1,'4a'),(4,'5d');

SELECT u.id_u, a.id_a, u.name, a.name_a FROM user u JOIN a USING(id_u);
SELECT u.id_u, b.id_b, u.name, b.name_b FROM user u JOIN b USING(id_u);

DELETE FROM user WHERE id_u = 1;

SELECT u.id_u, a.id_a, u.name, a.name_a FROM user u JOIN a USING(id_u);
SELECT u.id_u, b.id_b, u.name, b.name_b FROM user u JOIN b USING(id_u);
```

But if you want to delete all related table only without affecting the parents table. You could do a join to delete clouse, like this below

```
DELETE a,b FROM USER u JOIN b ON(u.id_u = b.id_u) JOIN a ON(u.id_u = a.id_u) WHERE u.id_u = 1;

SELECT * FROM user;
SELECT u.id_u, a.id_a, u.name, a.name_a FROM user u JOIN a USING(id_u);
SELECT u.id_u, b.id_b, u.name, b.name_b FROM user u JOIN b USING(id_u);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, if it is as you wrote, won't the user data be deleted as well? I want the user data and data of a specific table to be kept, and the rest of the data to be deleted.

Comment: @kunAguero Which table record you want to delete?

Comment: I have add some improvement if you want to delete all related record only, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good solution.

I created new user's data in the same.

And a new relationship with the new user , `A`.

And I wrote the code in a way to delete the existing user.

This solution is the same as the answer to the previous my question.
Previously, I couldn't write this code, so I wrote a new question.
thank you.!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).